# how to move files from one cloud space to another

Tags: file, download, cloud, file-transfer, operation

I have downloaded tons of files through cloud servers for example (**https://thefileslocker.com/**), and I have an account on the ***Mega*** cloud storage service and I'd like to copy the file from the **https://thefileslocker.com/** to my ***Mega*** account instead of downloading it and then reuploading it to my account.

================================================================================================

Is it possible to perform such an operation or not???
And if there's is a website that can do this, would you **kindly** put its link???

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0):

I've tried several method to transfer files between cloud services.

1. Multicloud https://www.multcloud.com/ it's have free and paid services to transfer between cloud.
2. For small files using mountain duck https://mountainduck.io/ if connector are available you could mount each cloud services as your hard drive, and move each file easily. It's paid services.

But i'm never try to transfer files from filelocker to mega.